# How the getState() function work under the component Model class?

Tags: php, joomla, joomla2.5

Under /components/com_content/models/category.php

```
function getItems()
{
    $params = $this->getState()->get('params');
    $limit = $this->getState('list.limit');
    // other code
```

Within the `getItems()` function, there is a function called `getState()`, it has a parameters `list.limit`. I want to ask what is the meaning of `list.limit`, and how the `getSatae()` function works? It can executed by parameter or no parameter, when to use either one?

Thanks

Comment: What version of Joomla do you have?

Answer (score 0):

This function is located in `/libraries/joomla/application/component/model.php` on line 395
Function notice pretty much speaks for itself.

Its basic model function (Joomla is based on MVC architecture) to get state variables.
The state object is storage for variables. (none by default)

list.limit defines how many items on page for example.

More info in [Joomla docs](http://docs.joomla.org/API17%3aJModel%3a%3agetState) or [Joomla MVC classes](http://www.i-programmer.info/programming/joomla/643-the-joomla-mvc-classes-.html?start=2)